# How to call information from one model to another Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller, codeigniter-3

I'm stuck on this from a while.Can't figured it out.I reed documantion, tried with several videos and tried like 10 different ways, nothing is working yet.So I have one view/model for one thing, in this example Destination and I have separate files for Offers.The controllers for both are in one file.I want tho the information that is in destination to go to Offers as well.Please help I can't figure out what I'm missing:
So here is the most important parts:

destination_model.php

```
<?php class Destination_model extends CI_Model

{
        public function getDestinationDetails($slug) {

        $this->db->select('
            id,
            title,
            information
        ');
        $this->db->where('slug', $slug);
        $query =  $this->db->get('destinations')->row();


        if(count($query) > 0)
        {
            return $query;
        }
        else
        {
            // redirect(base_url());
        }
}

public function getOffersByDestination($destination_id)
{

    $this->db->select('
            o.short_title,
            o.price,
            o.currency,
            o.information,
            o.long_title_slug,
            oi.image,
            c.slug as parent_category
    ');

    $this->db->from('offers o');
    $this->db->join('offers_images oi', 'oi.offer_id = o.id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('categories c', 'c.id = o.category');
    $this->db->group_by('o.id');
    $this->db->where('o.destination', $destination_id);
    $this->db->where('o.active', '1');
    return $this->db->get();

} }
```

And then in the controller for offers I put this:

```
$this->load->model('frontend/destination_model');
$this->params['destination'] = $this->destination_model->getOffersByDestination($data->id);
```

All I need is the title and the information about the destination.
Here is the whole controller for the offers:

```
                            $data = $this->slugs_model->getOfferDetails(strtok($this->uri->segment(2), "."));

                $this->load->model('frontend/offers_model');
                                                                                $this->load->model('frontend/destination_model');
                $this->params['main']       = 'frontend/pages/offer_details';

                $this->params['title']      = $data->long_title;
                $this->params['breadcumb']  = $this->slugs_model->getSlugName($this->uri->segment(1));
                $this->params['data']       = $data;
                $this->params['images']     = $this->slugs_model->getOfferImages($data->id);
                $this->params['similar']    = $this->slugs_model->getSimilarOffers($data->category, $data->id);
                $this->params['destination'] = $this->destination_model->getOffersByDestination($data->id);
                $this->params['offers']     = $this->offers_model->getImportantOffers($data->offers, $data->category, $data->id);
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to generate query results after you get it from model,
e.g: row_array(), this function returns a single result row.
here's the doc: [Generating Query Results](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/results.html)
try this:

```
$this->load->model('frontend/destination_model');
$data['destination'] = $this->destination_model->getOffersByDestination($data->id)->row_array();
$this->load->view('view_name', $data);
```

And in your view `echo $destination['attribut_name'];`, 
or you can print the array, to see if it's work `print_r($destination);`

Comment: How to echo in offer_details view the information for destinatinon for an example?